# Remove empty columns from read_csv()

Tags: r, dplyr, readr

I am trying to read the csv file linked [here](http://environmentalcomputing.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Snail_feeding.csv) using `read_csv()` from the readr package, and then remove empty columns.

If I use `read.csv()` instead, then the empty columns 8:12 can easily be removed using

```
library(dplyr)    
select(data, 1:7)
```

However, when I read the csv file using the `read_csv()` function, then the same code gives an error;

```
Error: found duplicated column name: NA, NA, NA, NA
```

How can I remove these empty columns?

It seems pointless to properly name empty columns just so I can remove them. I would prefer to use `read_csv()` rather than `read.csv()` as it makes life a bit easier later on in the analysis.

Comment: In that case, any reason for not using this `data <- data[,c(1:7)]`?

Answer (score 7):

You could do:

```
data <- data[,apply(data, 2, function(x) { sum(!is.na(x)) > 0 })]
```

This will keep only columns which are not entirely `NA`.

Or, if you have dplyr 0.5 installed, you can use the new `select_if` function to achieve the same effect:

```
has_data <- function(x) { sum(!is.na(x)) > 0 }
data <- data %>% select_if(has_data)
```

Comment: this should be a built-in by now.  2 years later?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about `read_csv`, but if you use `read.csv`, specify `colClasses` as "NULL" for the columns you don't want, you'll get what you're after (adjust the integers in the `rep` calls as needed:

```
read.csv( file = [yourfile],
        colClasses = c( rep("character",3), rep("NULL",5) )
)
```

The above will return only the first 3 columns, and disregard the following 5 columns.

ALTERNATIVE ANSWER:
Have you tried `fread`? It has a `select` argument, which might be useful for you, eg:

```
fread( [filename], select = c(1:3) )
```

It also has the benefit of being quite a bit faster than read.csv and read_csv. Here's a speed test with a particular file I have :

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark( 
fread = {rangerdata2 <- data.table::fread( filename, select = c(1:3) )}, 
read.csv = {rangerdata2 <- utils::read.csv( file = filename )[,1:3]}, 
read_csv = {rangerdata2 <- readr::read_csv( file = filename )[,1:3]}, 
times = 1000)

Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min       lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
 fread    1.22161  1.32841  1.464724  1.377178  1.442089  14.57102  1000 a  
 read.csv 18.25402 18.55992 19.664278 18.772855 19.565684 34.87589  1000   c
 read_csv 13.43166 13.76704 14.615746 13.975987 14.608822 33.36244  1000  b
```

Comment: For a valid comparison of `fread`, `read_csv` and `read.csv`, you need to use a much larger file. With a small file, you're mostly comparing whatever overhead is involved in calling the function, rather than the read speed, and all three functions are fast enough for the difference to be unnoticeable. I tested the three functions with a 50 MB file, 1 million rows, 7 columns (still relatively small, but big enough for this purpose) timings were (in seconds): `fread: 0.78`, `read_csv: 1.05`, `read.csv: 15.1`.

Comment: Just for the heck of it, I tested `fread` and `read_csv` on a faster computer with a 10-million row, 11 column, 1.8 GB csv file. Median timings based on 5 repetitions (in seconds): `fread: 21.3`, `read_csv: 23.0`.

Comment: Fair enough, but for the files I work with most often, those times are relevant (yes, even though the totals are small, making any improvement seem petty). If the overhead contributes significantly to the overall time, that matters to me. Thanks for the testing though, definitely interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Once your csv file is loaded into R as a data frame, you could do (assuming your data frame is called `dat`):

```
dat = dat[, sapply(dat, function(i) !all(is.na(i)))]
```

Initially, I was thinking that if you use `read_csv` you could do:

```
dat = dat[, !is.na(names(dat))]
```

because `read_csv` sets the names of all the empty columns to `NA`. However, this could be dangerous. If you have a column with no name in the first row, but some data, that column's name would also be `NA` and it would be deleted as well.